# python insert list with quotes into sqllite3

Tags: python, sql-insert

Im trying to insert data from a python list into sqllite table.

But list contains a strings with a quotes inside, like this:

```
sample = ['<h1 style="color:red">some text</h1>', 'some text']
```

So if i execute a query like this:

```
query = []
query.append("(\"" + "\", \"".join(sample) + "\")")
query = "INSERT INTO \"backup\" VALUES " + ", ".join(query)
```

im getting an error

*sqlite3.OperationalError: near "color": syntax error*

how to escape quotes?

upd. i need to do smth like this, but it doesnt works:

```
query.append("(\"" + "\", \"".join(x.replace("\"", "\\""") for x in sample) + "\")")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM: python believes that you wanted to finish your string there as you were using `"` to create your string.

SOLUTION:

**METHOD 1: Using escape characters**

When you want to use an actual quote use:

```
\"
```

**METHOD 2: using a different outer speech marks**

For example:

```
'that single quote was the beggining"this is in quotes" this is out'
```

You can also use triple quotes like so:

```
"""these are my tripe quotes ' I can embed single " and double quotes " as many times as I want' """
```

Comment: well 
i dont undertand how to escape

i need to do smth like this, but it doesnt works

query.append("(\"" + "\", \"".join(x.replace("\"", "\\""") for x in sample) + "\")")

Comment: @niko can you edit your answer to use this and can you separate as much of it as you can into readable variables on different lines, because I have no idea what that code is doing because it is not easy to read. Especially as it has errors.

Comment: the question is "how to use Method 1?" i updated the question.

Comment: Simple before every single quotation mark put a backslash first example: `\""` is wrong but `\"\"` is correct. Continue this for all of the string.